# Consulta a ORACLE que necesito modificar

Tags: oracle

Soy nuevo trabajando con ORACLE y me las ingenié para realizar una consulta que trae la información que necesito, el problema es que me las trae en filas y necesito que sea en columnas.

**Esta es la query:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) all_inclusives FROM aabb_platform.g_tb_outdoors
WHERE servicio_ratecode LIKE 'ALL%' AND
servicio_fecha BETWEEN TO_DATE('2019-10-12', 'yy-mm-dd') AND TO_DATE('2019-10-12', 'yy-mm-dd') 
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) full_board FROM aabb_platform.g_tb_outdoors
WHERE servicio_ratecode LIKE 'FULL%' AND
servicio_fecha BETWEEN TO_DATE('2019-10-12', 'yy-mm-dd') AND TO_DATE('2019-10-12', 'yy-mm-dd')
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) b_b FROM aabb_platform.g_tb_outdoors
WHERE servicio_ratecode LIKE '%BB%' AND
servicio_fecha BETWEEN TO_DATE('2019-10-12', 'yy-mm-dd') AND TO_DATE('2019-10-12', 'yy-mm-dd')
```

**Este es el resultado:**

```
ALL_INCLUSIVES
22
0
7
```

**Esto es lo que necesito lograr:**

```
ALL_INCLUSIVES FULL_BOARD B_B
      22           0       7
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, Procura siempre incluir la descripción de tu tabla (la sentencia DDL, por ejemplo) para saber sobre qué estás ejecutando tu consulta

Comment: Construye un CROSSTAB utilizando PIVOT.
https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html

Answer (score 2):

Compañeros,

Encontré la forma de hacerlo y es la siguiente:

```
SELECT SERVICIO_FECHA,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN SERVICIO_RATECODE LIKE 'ALL%' THEN 1 END) AS ALL_INCLUSIVE,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN SERVICIO_RATECODE LIKE 'FULL%' THEN 1 END) AS FULL_BOARD,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN SERVICIO_RATECODE LIKE '%BB%' THEN 1 END) AS B_B
FROM AABB_PLATFORM.G_TB_OUTDOORS
WHERE SERVICIO_FECHA BETWEEN TO_DATE('2019-10-12', 'yy-mm-dd') AND TO_DATE('2019-10-12', 'yy-mm-dd')
GROUP BY SERVICIO_FECHA
```